# no matching function for call to 'QSqlDatabase::database(const char [5], QString&)'

Tags: sql, qt, qt5, qsqldatabase

В чём причина ошибки?

```
no matching function for call to 'QSqlDatabase::database(const char [5], QString&)'    QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::database("dbsql", connectionName);

bool createConnectionToThread(QString dbName)
{
    QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL", dbName);
    db.setDatabaseName("dgis");
    db.setUserName("root");
    db.setHostName("localhost");
    db.setPassword("golos123");
    qDebug() << db.drivers();
    if (!db.open()) {
        qDebug() << "Cannot open database: " << db.lastError();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
...
      QString connectionName = QString(random.go());
      createConnectionToThread(connectionName);
      QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::database("dgis", connectionName);
...
```

Comment: открываем документацию и смотрим на функцию database - там такая сигнатура `QSqlDatabase QSqlDatabase::database(const QString &connectionName = QLatin1String( defaultConnection ), bool open = true)` - то есть два параметра - строка и булево. А Вы пытаетесь дать ему строку и строку.

Comment: @KoVadim вы совершенно правы, оформите пожалуйста в виде ответа, я его зачту.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Согласно [документации](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqldatabase.html#database), сигнатура функции database следующая `QSqlDatabase QSqlDatabase::database(const QString &connectionName = QLatin1String( defaultConnection ), bool open = true)` - то есть два параметра - строка и булево. А Вы пытаетесь дать ему строку. Естественно оно не может. А что там нужно вписать - это нужно разбираться, скорее всего true.